# Is $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ virtually torsion free?

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, p-adic-groups, arithmetic-groups

If so, is there a way to conclude this from Malcev's theorem?

In general, what is known about virtually torsion freeness of non-finitely generated linear groups?

Comment: If you take an open subgroup of the form $U=SL_n(p^m {\mathbb Z}_p)$ (congruence subgroup of level $p^m$  ) then the log  map on this is an isomorphism  onto the image. In particular, if $g\in U$ such that $g^k=1$ then $klog (g)=0$ whence $log g=0$ hence $g=1$; that is, $U$ is torsion-free.

Answer (score 13):

$SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is virtually torsion free as it is $p$-adic analytic and therefore contains a uniformly powerful open subgroup.