# Is $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ virtually torsion-free?

Tags: gr.group-theory, p-adic-groups

Recall that a group is *virtually torsion-free* if it admits a finite index subgroup which is torsion-free.

**Question**. Is $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ virtually torsion-free for $n > 1$?

**Comments**.

1. Note that $\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{Q}_p) = \mathbb{Q}_p^*$ is virtually torsion-free.
2. We know by a theorem of Selberg that for a field $K$ of characteristic 0, any finitely generated subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ is virtually torsion-free. However, this does not apply to $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ as it is not finitely generated; the diagonal matrices give a copy of $\mathbb{Q}_p^*$, which is uncountably infinite.
3. A related question can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265058/is-sl-n-mathbbz-p-virtually-torsion-free) where it is shown that $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is virtually torsion-free as it is a compact $p$-adic analytic group.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: $SL_n(\mathbb Q)$ is simple modulo centre and hence does not have subgroups of finite index. It also does have torsion elements. Therefore, it is not virtually torsion free.

Comment: $SL_1(Q_p)$ is not $Q_p^*$, it is just the trivial group.

Comment: @YCor That was rather silly of me! Thank you for the comment. I have removed that comment from the question.

Comment: @Venkataramana Thank you for the comment! I believe this answers the question since virtual torsion freeness is inherited by subgroups.

Comment: By the way, I think that the proof that ${\rm SL}(n, \mathbb{Z}_{p})$ is virtually torsion free is not that complicated: the matrices congruent (elementwise) to the identity (mod $p$) form a torsion-free normal subgroup of finite index, and the quotient group by that normal subgroup is finite.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson One needs mod 4 for $p=2$.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, thanks, I had forgotten about that (standard) exception (but still, the argument is fairly elementary in the case $p=2$ as well).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson but the $p$-analytic argument is also not complicated, and even related. Basically, for $A$ close enough to the identity, $\|A^p-1\|<\|A-1\|$, which implies that $A$ has infinite order (if $\neq 1$).

Comment: @YCor : Sure, I know the argument, and it is not basically different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (this was already answered in comments).

$\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is generated by its unipotent 1-parameter subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}_p$, hence it has no proper subgroup of finite index. Hence, if it were virtually torsion-free, it would be torsion-free, which is not the case (for $n\ge 2$) as it has an element of order $2$.